# Even regular planar graphs without 2-cycles

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, planar-graphs

Related to another question I asked, some questions came up, the most important is the following:

> Are there any 4-regular planar graphs without 2-cycles + 3-cycles?

Could someone draw an example if there is one? I couldn't find any paper that answers this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a connected planar 4-regular graph without cycles of length less than 4 we have $E=2V$ and $2E\geqslant 4F$ (since every face has at least 4 edges and every edge belongs to at most 2 faces). Thus $2E\geqslant 2V+2F$, contradiction to Euler formula $E+2=V+F$.

Answer (score 0):

For a plane 4-valent connected graph without loops twice the number of 2-gons plus the number of 3-gons must be at least 8, a result that follows from Euler’s formula.

Answer (score 0):

There is an infinite example: the infinite grid-graph!

Comment: I wasn't precise in my question. I was interested in S^3 , a rather finite one :D

Comment: Ah yes. I was going to argue that this is still interesting. But you could even do stupider things like the infinite 4-regular tree, so this isn't unique or anything.

Comment: maybe you want to check out my previous question on the platform, that is related to this one (still no answer) > "Three-dimensional triangulations with fixed number of vertices"